# Convert bytes32 address into normal address?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have bytes32 address as shown below:
`'0x000000000000000000000000697cb3a91d22f4cb39aeea7eb4a410fedd0bbe06'`

How can I convert the above given bytes 32 in an address as shown below:
`0x697cB3a91d22F4cB39AeEA7Eb4A410FeDD0bBE06`

Comment: did you try to simply cast it : `address(bytesString)`

Comment: gives error ```TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes32" to "address"```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this will work fine:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.16 <0.9.0;

contract Convertion {
    function test(bytes32 _input) external pure returns (address) {
        return address(uint160(uint256(_input)));
    }
}
```

Refer [Solidity doc](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.9/types.html#address):

> If you convert a type that uses a larger byte size to an `address`, for
> example `bytes32`, then the `address` is truncated. To reduce conversion
> ambiguity version 0.4.24 and higher of the compiler force you make the
> truncation explicit in the conversion. Take for example the address
> `0x111122223333444455556666777788889999AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFCCCC`.
>
> You can use `address(uint160(bytes20(b)))`, which results in
> `0x111122223333444455556666777788889999aAaa`, or you can use
> `address(uint160(uint256(b)))`, which results in
> `0x777788889999AaAAbBbbCcccddDdeeeEfFFfCcCc`.

Comment: any idea how we can do the same with web3.js?